# Colcon select Python version

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I encountered problems while setting up Github Actions for a ROS2 Humble project on Windows.
I used an [action](https://github.com/ros-tooling/setup-ros) for setting up ROS2 since it seemed pretty complicated on Windows which uses Python version 3.7.

The problem is that colcon selects Python version 3.11 and fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catkin_pkg'` when building packages.

I tried using `-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=...` or Pythons`s virtual environments and created an [issue](https://github.com/ros-tooling/setup-ros/issues/552) at the repository containing the action which contains links to the workflow and logs, does anybody know a way of forcing colcon to use a particular Python version?

Edit: I also tried replacing the actions and doing everything by my self but the error persists.

```
2023-05-05T14:34:04.6016022Z Starting >>> dotnet_cmake_module
2023-05-05T14:34:04.7077082Z Starting >>> ament_cmake_export_assemblies
2023-05-05T14:34:05.9151305Z Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
2023-05-05T14:34:05.9152542Z Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
2023-05-05T14:34:21.1725257Z -- Found ament_cmake_core: 1.3.3 (C:/dev/humble/ros2-windows/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake)
2023-05-05T14:34:21.1726025Z -- Found ament_cmake: 1.3.3 (C:/dev/humble/ros2-windows/share/ament_cmake/cmake)
2023-05-05T14:34:42.3629746Z -- Found Python3: C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.11.3/x86/python3.exe (found version "3.11.3") found components: Interpreter 
2023-05-05T14:34:42.3630442Z [Processing: ament_cmake_export_assemblies, dotnet_cmake_module]
2023-05-05T14:34:42.3631019Z -- Found Python3: C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.11.3/x86/python3.exe (found version "3.11.3") found components: Interpreter 
2023-05-05T14:34:42.6704445Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-05-05T14:34:42.6705318Z   File "C:\dev\humble\ros2-windows\share\ament_cmake_core\cmake\core\package_xml_2_cmake.py", line 22, in <module>
2023-05-05T14:34:42.6705850Z     from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package_string
2023-05-05T14:34:42.6706309Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415600/colcon-select-python-version/) by [Deric](https://answers.ros.org/users/114248/deric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2023-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the log information, it's clear this is unrelated to colcon; it's CMake that's finding the wrong version of python when building the `ament_cmake_export_assemblies` package. The script that fails is invoked from inside the call to `ament_package` and it seems to use the version of python found [here](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/77c1dd758dc65f80bd6644ec80261c0f3bfa6f7f/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/python.cmake#L21) which happens when `find_package(ament_cmake)` is called. Looking at the CMake docs for finding Python, it looks like the main way to control which one is found is via the [Python3_ROOT_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html#hints) variable. You could try to set it to the one you want as a `--cmake-arg` in the colcon invocation or via `colcon.pkg` file for that package specifically.

---

Original answer:

Colcon doesn't "select" a python version. Like all python tools, it uses the version of the environment it was installed into. The script that runs when you invoke `colcon` as an executable command is a python file generated in the install process and its first line is a shebang pointing to the python interpreter of the environment. On Ubuntu, when you do `apt install python3-colcon` it points to `/usr/bin/python3` since it's using the global system environment. But you can also `pip install` it in other places (like a virtual env) and then it will point to that interpreter instead. Or alternatively, if you have a python environment which can see the installed colcon packages (like a virtual env which can see system packages), you can run colcon inside that environment through it's interpreter directly via `python -m colcon`.

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2023-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Deric](https://answers.ros.org/users/114248/deric/) on 2023-05-24**:
Thank you for your response, but sadly running colcon with `python -m colcon` does not prevent the wrong Python version (3.11) from being selected when building packages.

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2023-05-25**:
That would indicate your `python` command points to a 3.11 version, which you can double check with `python --version`. So you need to sort out calling the version you actually want.

**Comment by [Deric](https://answers.ros.org/users/114248/deric/) on 2023-05-26**:
`python --version` returns the version which I installed (3.7.9)

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2023-05-31**:
Perhaps you can post more details/logs on how you know a different python version is involved?

**Comment by [Deric](https://answers.ros.org/users/114248/deric/) on 2023-06-02**:
I added the part of the log which contains the selected Python version and the error, the full log is available at the Issue which I linked.

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2023-06-02**:
Thanks for the log info, that cleared things up quite a bit. It would have been nice to have that pasted from the start. Reviewing an attached zip file of logs on a linked issue is a bit much to ask from question answerers.

**Comment by [Deric](https://answers.ros.org/users/114248/deric/) on 2023-06-07**:
Sorry, I will try to be more forthcoming next time

**Comment by [rakin374](https://answers.ros.org/users/164650/rakin374/) on 2023-07-21**:
Hey did you guys end up solving this issue? I am stuck on it now

**Comment by [Deric](https://answers.ros.org/users/114248/deric/) on 2023-07-22**:
I noticed that `Python3_FIND_STRATEGY` has to be set to `LOCATION` to prevent CMake from using the highest Python Version available, the final colcon args are `-DPython3_ROOT_DIR=C:Path/to/Python -DPython3_FIND_STRATEGY=LOCATION -DPython3_FIND_REGISTRY=NEVER`.